# Applying css to LineChart JavaFx chart

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am filling a LineChat chart with data and sometimes I need to redraw it. The drawGraph() method is attached to the button click event (we press it to redraw the graph). I want the first data series to have transparent markers and the second data series to have transparent lines. For this I use css. On the first call to the drawGraph() method, everything works fine, and I get this picture:
[It should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0SHq.png)

I try to make it so that every time I redraw the chart, I get the 1st picture

But from the next redrawings, the following picture starts to be displayed every other time:
[It should not be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UulqP.png)

That is, a graph is displayed every other time without applying css to it, and one data series overlaps another

Style sheet:

```
/* Removes points from a data series */
.default-color0.chart-line-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
/* Removes lines from a data series */
.default-color1.chart-series-line {
    -fx-stroke: transparent;
}
```

Chart redrawing method (from ApplicationController):

```
   double[] X = new double[] {1,2,3,4,5};
   double[] Y = new double[] {1.9,5.5,10,15,21};

   public void drawGraph() {
        //clear the Chart
        lineChart.getData().clear();

        //Data series #1
        ObservableList<XYChart.Data> datas = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

        //Filling series #1
        for(int i=0; i< X.length; i++){
            datas.add(new XYChart.Data(X[i],Y[i]));
        }
        series.setData(datas);

        //Data series #2
        ObservableList<XYChart.Data> datas1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        
        //Filling series #2     
        for(int i=0; i< X.length; i++){
            datas1.add(new XYChart.Data(X[i],Y[i]));
        }
        series1.setData(datas1);

        //lineChart.setStyle();
        lineChart.getStylesheets().add(HelloApplication.class.getResource("style.css")
                .toExternalForm());
        lineChart.getData().add(series);
        lineChart.getData().add(series1);
    }
```

Comment: "LineChat chart with data and sometimes I need to redraw it" -> why?

Comment: If the purpose of the redraw is to apply a new set of data to the chart, then my suggestion would be to replace the data in the existing series on the redraw and not do anything else.  If you continue to have issues (I am not quite sure what your issue actually is), then I would advise just replacing the entire LineChart with a new one with your new data, generated exactly the same way you generated the original chart.

Comment: @jewelsea, Thanks for your advice.  It was wrong to create new data series and place them on the chart at each redraw, and even more so - to apply a style sheet at each redraw.
It turned out to be enough to change the current data series. I applied the style sheet once - when filling the chart with data series

Answer (score 0):

It was bad practice to create new data series and place them on the chart instead of the old ones. Also, it was not worth using a style sheet for each new data redrawing.
What I did was to fill in the graph for the first time, and when it was redrawn, I replaced it in the series as follows.

```
//We get a series:
XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = lineChart.getData().get(0);

//Let's remove all elements in the series:
series.getData().clear();

//We add elements to the series like this:
series.getData().add(new LineChart.Data<Number,Number>(1, 2));
```